# How to check if Twitter Bootstrap is present?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mootools

Working with Joomla 30 which has Mootools, jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap but each can be turned off.

I need to check if bootstrap is present.

For moo and jq we can do

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  

// do stuff
}
```

But how do we check if Bootstrap is present? And how do we check it with mootools or pure js no libs?

Answer (score 2):

This will be quite a bit harder with Bootstrap (than, say, checking for jQuery) because bootstrap doesn't leak a definitive variable into the global namespace. What you *could* do is to (a) first check for jQuery (as bootstrap seems to depend on it) and then either:

a) iterate over $("link") to check for **attr("href").indexOf("/bootstrap.")>=0** and/or iterate over *$("script") to check **attr("src").indexOf("/bootstrap.")>=0**. Now this is of course a very non-scientific way to check for this. (Note: this check uses jQuery, but this should be ok as per the jQuery-dependency of bootstrap)

b) Another - maybe more scientific - idea would be to check for the presence of individual features. Say, check for **($.fn.modal && $.fn.affix && $.fn.typeahead && ...)**. This might yield false positives (if the developer uses other plugins with the same names) or even false negatives if the developer has used a custom combination of bootstrap features.

Another option would be to check for typical CSS classes like ".form-horizontal" and ".pre-scrollable" by assigning them to a temporary element and programmatically checking their runtime style. But this might be a bit harder and could *also* result in false positives/negatives if a developer has customized the styles.

So I guess there is no simple answer ...

Comment: I ended up checking for functions and in my case they are all in 1 file

Answer (score 0):

I think I fund a solution if anyone has better one please advise

this is within mootools domready

```
if((typeof jQuery == 'function' && typeof jQuery.fn.popover == 'undefined') || (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')){

//  BS is not here 

}
```

we can check for other bootstrap function like
jQuery.fn.tooltip
 , like said this is particular to Joomla 3.0 version of bootstrap since all its plugins are in 1 min file ,

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your body-tag? Then you could add a data-attribute like `data-bootstrap="1"` and check if it is present, or even change the value to `0` if needed.

Comment: tweaking the html is not a point , there are many variations we could do but I think that this should have been strait forward since TBS is so widely used now.